# Have before filter prevent ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my controller I have:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(..)
{
  .OnActionE..
  if(...)
  {
    Response.Redirect("/Login");
  }
}

public ActionResponse Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

The documentation states that `OnActionExecuting` is run before `Index()` however this is not true. While `Response.Redirect` does happen it's only after `Index` has been evaluated. Is it possible have the filter prevent Index from executing ?

Comment: What is the `.OnActionE..` bit? It's generally better to err on the side of posting too much code than potentially redacting something that is actually the source of the issue, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: The documentation is 100% accurate, The problem is you're using the feature wrong. It's usually best to assume you're doing something wrong than that you're the first person to find a problem in a feature that thousands of developers use successfully every day.

Comment: @CraigW. How am I using it wrong. David posted the solution which is what I expected just could not dig it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnActionExecuting` is running before the action, but it's not *stopping* the action from also running.  To do that, you can set the `Result` property of the `ActionExecutingContext`.  Something like this perhaps:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Login");
}
```

If a `Result` is set anywhere in the framework pipeline, that should prevent subsequent actions (including other filters) from executing.